# Rails5 Directly inheriting from from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Sorcery Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

I am trying to migrate a Rails 3 app. I installed Rails v 5.1.5 using RVM.
When trying db:migrate, I get the following.

rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:

class SorceryCore < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]

Here is the Class Definition for Sorcerycore:

```
class SorceryCore < <%= migration_class_name %>        


  def change
    create_table :<%= model_class_name.tableize %> do |t|
      t.string :email,            :null => false
      t.string :crypted_password
      t.string :salt

      t.timestamps                :null => false
    end

    add_index :<%= model_class_name.tableize %>, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, I see that I need to work on the individual migrations.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You have to specify the version in brackets like it says.  Have you added any migrations since upgrading?

Example change from:

`class SorceryCore < ActiveRecord::Migration`

to

`class SorceryCore < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]`

You can add the version to all migrations by running this from your Rails root directory:

```
grep -rl ActiveRecord::Migration$ db | xargs sed -i "" "s/ActiveRecord::Migration/ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]/g"
```

Comment: The class is defined in SorceryCore like so.
class SorceryCore < <%= migration_class_name %>  So, how would I add ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]? And from where in the directory structure should I run your grep command?

Comment: @ubiquitousDave - Ahh, I see.  I thought that was an example from your code.  Are you on the latest version of the `sorcery` gem?  It looks like they define `migration_class_name` from the `Rails::VERSION::MAJOR` variable.

Comment: https://github.com/Sorcery/sorcery/blob/4e3fcdb8df16912424281322ce9f2862937846fc/lib/generators/sorcery/install_generator.rb is the source for that.  I believe if you are on that latest version of sorcery - `gem update sorcery`...assuming your `Gemfile` is not locked to an older version, it will work.

Comment: Ok, I see that I need to work on the individual migrations. That did it!

Comment: Any thoughts on how to handle this if the migrations are part of a gem we don't own/manage.

Comment: If there isn't a newer version of the gem available, and you are trying to use it in a newer version of Rails, you might have to fork the repository, fix the migrations, push it up, and use your forked version of the repository.  You might have to update some other dependencies as well.

Comment: Slightly changed code worked for Redmine plugins  `grep -rl ActiveRecord::Migration$ db | xargs sed -i 's/ActiveRecord::Migration/ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]/g'`

Comment: I want to say thank you. I was doing this by hand with more than 200++ migrations. I was going to write a script on it until I saw this. THANK YOU!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

In my case is that I was using and out-dated version of `data_migrate`:

```
bundle update data_migrate
# Using data_migrate 6.3.0 (was 5.3.2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add your migration version at last Like

```
class SorceryCore < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
```

so here `[5.1]` is your version so add version

if you don't know the version please check your previous migration, may you find there...